# Cannot install matplotlib on Intel Edison

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, yocto, intel-edison

I am trying to install matplotlib on my Intel Edison board but I am taking errors. I installed Numpy and Spicy successfully but could not manage to install matplotlib.

I am getting this error

```
root@edisonwbl:~# pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading matplotlib-2.0.2.tar.gz (53.9MB)
    99% |############################### | 53.9MB 623kB/s eta 0:00:01Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 882, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 603, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 571, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 139, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 560, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 357, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 314, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 63, in read
    self._close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 50, in _close
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 275, in cache_response
    self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 87, in dumps
    ).encode("utf8"),
MemoryError
```

I have Yocto on Edison and firmware version is 201606061707

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

**--- Edit ---**

I found the solution. freetype2 and libpng packages cannot be installed so I installed them manually and problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to uninstall python and install **[Anaconda2](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)** for python 2.7. It comes with all necessary module, including matplolib, numpy, pandas all.

follow this link: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: Does Linux (Yocto) in Intel Edison supports Anaconda?

Comment: I am getting this error @ShahariarRabby

Anaconda2 will now be installed into this location:
/home/root/anaconda2

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/root/anaconda2] >>>
PREFIX=/home/root/anaconda2
tar: unrecognized option '--no-same-owner'
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2016-06-06 14:50:27 PDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: tar -[cxtZzJjahmvO] [-X FILE] [-T FILE] [-f TARFILE] [-C DIR] [FILE]...

ERROR: could not extract tar starting at line 592